# DockStyle.Fill not applied until parent form resize

Tags: c#, forms, winforms

I am adding a form as a child to a parent form. In the constructor for the child form I have passed in the parent and have after `initializeComponent`:

```
this.Parent = parent
this.Dock = DockStyle.Fill
```

But the child form has the default size until the window is resized.
I have tried calling `this.Invalidate` in the form in the _load event and in the constructor and this has had no effect.

Comment: This is interesting case for me, I want to know the reason and the solution as well. upvoted..

Comment: When you say form you refers to a `Form` or  a `Control`?